# Getting java method reflection from .jar to Python

Tags: java, python

I'm working on the docs of a module and I need to add both the Python and Java signatures to a html.

In order to get the Python signatures I'm doing:

```
method = getattr(cv2, str(function_name))
signature = str(method.__doc__)
```

and I'm getting as a result something like, i.e.:

```
x, y = cv2.polarToCart(magnitude, angle[, x[, y[, angleInDegrees]]])
```

Now, I wanted to do the same for Java.

Is there a way to get a Java method signature to a Python string? Like a reflection from the .jar file? I wanted to get both the signatures and default **parameters names** for a given function_name.

I also don't know the name of the class inside the .jar, I only know the name of the function.

Comment: So you want to get a Java method, from a given Jar in Python? How do you identify the method? Do you have a method name and classpath?

Comment: Java does not support default arguments. You need to overload your functions.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ overloading is a way to get the default arguments or to set new ones?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this *from Python* or an equivalent way to do it *in Java*? You probably can't get the parameter names in Java, only the types.

Comment: Maybe read the bytecode, parse it, and find the method?

Comment: @DavidConrad I wanted to get the signature to a Python string so that I can add it to the html directly. But anyway if I do it in Java I can write it to a temp txt file and read that file from Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can get the information from the name and parameter types of the method like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method square = Foo.class.getMethod("square", new Class<?>[] { int.class });
        System.out.println(square);
    }

    public int square(int x) {
        return x * x;
    }
}
```

If you only have the method name (and, assuming it is unique, that is, that the method is not overloaded) you could do something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method square = Arrays.stream(Foo.class.getMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("square"))
                .findFirst().get();
        System.out.println(square);
    }

    public int square(int x) {
        return x * x;
    }
}
```

Either one will print out:

```
public int Foo.square(int)
```

You could also call `toString()` on the `Method`; `System.out.println` is calling `toString()` since it was called with an object. As you can see, the string includes the access modifiers, static-ness (absent here since it's not a static method), return type, fully-qualified method name, and parameter types, but not parameter names. It would not include type information for a generic method; for a generic method, it would only include the erased types. (If you don't know what that means, it is probably not relevant to your use case.)

I don't know anything about Java/Python interop, so I don't know how you could do this from Python.

Comment: Is there a way to get only the arguments/parameters names? like the Python example. For example in your sample I would like to print out : `public int Foo.square(int x)`

Comment: @João Not that I know of.